# How to convert a number for a salary amount, to a specific, 9 digit, format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

If I enter a salary dollar amount as 34512.15, I'd like to have a formula return this amount in a specific format as follows:

M(HT)(TT)(TH)HTOCC

M=Millions
(HT)=Hundred Thousands
(TT)=Ten Thousands
(TH)=Thousands
H=Hundreds
T=Tens
O=Ones
CC=Cents

The input may or may not include decimals, but the return value should not.

Also, where there is no value provided for any place value, a zero should be populated in the return value.  So, in the above example, the output should be "003451215" without the quotations.  Another example:  56000 salary would return as "005600000".  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: So far, i've tried to use the REPT function to add zeros to either end, but this doesn't take into account how different users may input the salary amount, e.g. if one includes decimals, but another doesn't, it would return different values.  Even if all users used the same value, my current formula only adds zeros to the front OR back, so depending on the value, it could still be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Combine the `SUBSTITUTE` and `TEXT` functions. You may have to change the `"."` based on your regional settings. To convert the value shown in `A1` the formula is:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"0000000.00"),".","")
```

Note that it will only convert numeric values. Any text or errors are simply returned unchanged.

If you put in very large values, the result will be longer. I.E., it doesn't chop of the digit in the billions place. If you want something that does that, use this instead:

```
 =RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"0000000.00"),".",""),9)
```

Comment: this worked on all points, including no decimal in either scenario.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @ZechLumpkin Glad it worked. barry houdini's solution would also work if you don't have any letters mixed in. In that case, mine returns zeroes and his returns error. For whichever works best, click the check mark underneath the upvote / downvote buttons to the left to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you multiply by 100 that will get rid of the decimal point, then you can just use TEXT function to give you the leading zeroes, e.g. with your salary amount in A1

`=TEXT(A1*100,"000000000")`

Comment: This is simpler but will return an error if `A1` contains text. Depending on OP's setup, this may or may not be the better solution.